# Flutter - How get use data in FFMPEG commands (input & output)

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

In Flutter, How to use data in FFMPEG commands (input & output).
Like:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 -i 4.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp3
```

2 Question regarding this command:

1. What is the path to bring the '1.mp3', '2.mp3'... to the FFMPEG.
2. Where is the 'output.mp3' goes to? eventually?

Didn't find any solution, let's speak locally and after that remotely (API/SERVER).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the path to bring the '1.mp3', '2.mp3'... to the FFMPEG.

Your `ffmpeg` command in your question assumes `1.mp3` and `2.mp3` are in the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) that `ffmpeg` is being executed in.

For example, in Linux if the files are in `/home/aix/music`, then you would have to navigate to `/home/aix/music` in your terminal (such as by running `cd /home/aix/music`) before running the `ffmpeg` command shown in your question.

Or, provide the full path to the files and the current directory will not matter:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/aix/videos/1.mp4 -i /home/aix/videos/2.mp4 ...
```

> Where is the 'output.mp3' goes to? eventually?

`output.mp3` goes wherever you tell it to. Because no path was provided the `ffmpeg` command in your question it will output `output.mp3` into the current directory.

Or, provide the full path to output `output.mp3` in the desired directory:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 /home/aix/music/encoded/output.mp3
```